# How to set the displayed text when an item is chosen in selectize.js?

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js for a multiple select on my webpage.
HTML Snippet:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select_dd" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="TEXT_TO_DISPLAY">
      DECRIPTION
   </option>
</select>
```

But when I choose the item, the text displayed in the selections input box is DESCRIPTION. How I display the "value" attribute instead of the "text" attribute.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the `render` option: this has the advantage that you can make the option text and the selected text whatever you choose:

```js
$('#select_dd').selectize({
      render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
         return '<div>' + item.text + ' </div>';
        },
        item: function(item, escape) {
          return '<div>' + item.value + ' whatever </div>';
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <select class="form-control" id="select_dd" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="TEXT_TO_DISPLAY_1">DECRIPTION 1</option>
    <option value="TEXT_TO_DISPLAY_2">DECRIPTION 2</option>
    <option value="TEXT_TO_DISPLAY_3">DECRIPTION 3</option>
  </select>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```